# react-router 6.0 - useLoaderData returns a promise. Cannot display data

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

https://github.com/erAnusriM/react_router_trial
The above is my github repository.
How do I achieve to print the list of users returned from the API in App.jsx file
When I print the value of result on console, it gives me a Response object.

**Expected Behavior**
The result should be an array object

**Actual Behavior**
The result is a Response object

Reference https://reactrouter.com/en/main/hooks/use-loader-data

Following is my source code

main.jsx

```
import React, { useRef } from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom/client";
import { createBrowserRouter, defer, RouterProvider } from "react-router-dom";
import Homepage from "./App";
import "./index.css";

const router = createBrowserRouter([
  {
    path: "/",
    element: <Homepage />,

    loader: async ({ request, params }) => {
        
      const data = fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users');

      return defer({
        results: data,
      });
    },
  },
]);

ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById("root")).render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <RouterProvider router={router} />
  </React.StrictMode>
);
```

App.jsx

```
import React, { useState } from 'react'
import { useLoaderData, Await, useAsyncValue } from "react-router-dom";
import reactLogo from './assets/react.svg'
import './App.css'

const Homepage = () => {
  const {results} = useLoaderData()

 // Render the data when it is available
  return <React.Suspense
  fallback={<p>Loading data...</p>}
>

  <Await
    resolve={results}
    errorElement={
      <p>Error loading data</p>
    }
      
  >
    
     {(results) => {
       console.log("results", results); <== **prints results as a Response object not array**
       return <>Hello</>;
     }}
  
    
  </Await>
</React.Suspense>
};

export default Homepage;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your `loader` function `data` is the `fetch` response value, not the actual data. `"https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users"` returns a JSON value that must ***also*** be accessed. This is another Promise that should be awaited.

A typical loader flow may look something like:

```js
loader: async ({ request, params }) => {
  const response = await fetch("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users");

  return { results: response.json() };
}
```

```js
const { results } = useLoaderData();
```

The `defer` utility is used when this loader may take *more* time than is usual.

```js
loader: async ({ request, params }) => {
  const response = await fetch("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users");

  return defer({
    results: response.json()
  });
}
```

```
const Homepage = () => {
  const { results } = useLoaderData();

  // Render the data when it is available
  return (
    <React.Suspense fallback={<p>Loading data...</p>}>
      <Await resolve={results} errorElement={<p>Error loading data</p>}>
        {(results) => {
          console.log({ results }); // <-- array of objects
          return <>Hello</>;
        }}
      </Await>
    </React.Suspense>
  );
};
```